# How to set the port for HTTP(S) in EC2 Security Group Inbound settings for a secure public iPython Notebook server?

Tags: https, amazon-ec2, port, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Having installed ipython on my Amazon Web Services EC2 instance, I am trying to run a public server for the iPython HTML notebook by following instructions found here: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/htmlnotebook.html ('Quick Howto: running a public notebook server').  So I have a hashed password and a self-signed ssl certificate.

```
(sci_3.3.2)ubuntu@ip-xx:~/.ipython/profile_nbserver$ ipython3 notebook --profile=nbserver
[NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: '/home/ubuntu/.ipython/profile_nbserver'
[NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from /home/ubuntu/.ipython/profile_nbserver
[NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: https://[all ip addresses on your system]:9999/
[NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels.
```

Suppose my EC2 instance's public DNS name is 'ec2-12345.compute.amazonaws.com', if I enter the url 'https://ec2-12345.compute.amazonaws.com:9999' into my web browser, it hangs before giving:
[image: This web page is not available]

The same thing happens if I use HTTP (in which case I don't use the ssl certificate when starting the notebook server).  At this point, I have already created Inbound rules allowing HTTP and HTTPS in EC2 Security Group settings.  But when creating these, port 80 and 443 are assigned, respectively, and I think because none of these are port 9999, at which the ipython notebook is being served, the above url just hangs.

Because there's not an option to choose the port number when creating Inbound rules for HTTP and HTTPS, I tried creating Custom TCP rules, which do allow port numbers to be chosen, and after choosing port 9999, I find that I can access ipython notebook in my web browser. However, I see this in the url:

[image: cross https]

in my web browser, and this:

[image: tornado warning]

at the terminal.  Does this mean I'm not using https?  Is this as intended by the ipython documentation?  If not, is there a way to choose the port number when creating Inbound rules for HTTP and HTTPS?

When I open up a notebook from the dashboard, I see this in the terminal:

[image: tcp]

which seems to confirm that indeed TCP is used instead of HTTPS.

I'm not familiar with network protocols and ports.  Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP and HTTPs are both a TCP/IP protocol:

http://www.w3schools.com/tcpip/tcpip_protocols.asp

I also found this video which confirms this:
http://youtu.be/JMedTCa5lec?t=4m29s

and the red, crossed-out https in the url reflects the unverified certificate (probably because it's self-signed).